# While using memory leak detection tools why do they ask us to close the application before getting final figures

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I don't understand why while using memory leak detection tools like MemoryValidator they say to attach the memory leak detection tool to the process we want to monitor, then close down the application gracefully and look for the leaked objects reported. Lets say the application is a transactional one, then after every transaction any objects used for the transaction should be freed. Anything left unfreed is a memory leak. There is no need to wait till the application ends, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer from Overbose. Only at the very end, once all destructors have been executed, and all resources should have been cleaned up, the situation can be evaluated by the tool.

Comment: So if an application keeps storing up objects that are no longer needed, and only deletes them at the very end in the destructor, such an application might as well not delete them even there, because anyway the application is shutting down. Such an application will not be reported as leaking memory, although for all practical purposes, it is.

Comment: how do you think to establish when these objects are no longer needed?

Comment: That depends on the resource allocation strategy. Sometimes it is done on purpose. If resources are taken from resource pools and given back to the pool when they are not needed anymore, they stay in the app. Also resources have different life durations. Only the app can know, how long the resource really is in use.

Comment: A leak finder tool can find resources that slipped through the normal house keeping for resources and simply were forgotten to clean up.

Comment: "how do you think to establish when these objects are no longer needed" The leak detector tool need not establish anything. It can just show what objects are stilling alive in the heap, and the user can do the establishing whether it is a leak or not. Also remember that memory used in dependent libraries also add up to the memory usage. There can be no question the memory used by a library should be freed as and when, except for the dependent library object itself and its member variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say the application is a
>   transactional one, then after every
>   transaction any objects used for the
>   transaction should be freed

How do you pretend that the leak detection tool can know that?
In addition there is something known as [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: I'm saying why can't they just allow us to check what are the leaked objects at any given time, instead of having to close down the applicatio. I don't care to read about some theoritical halting problem. I'm a more practical man.